# Can Safari show ReCaptcha in a modal dialog?

Tags: jquery, safari, webkit, modal-dialog, recaptcha

I'm trying to show *ReCaptcha* in a modal (jquery) dialog. I've tried it with blockUI, SimpelModal and ThickBox. With every one of them, it works perfectly in Firefox, and not at all in Safari (haven't tested Chrome).

What happens is that when the dialog opens, Safari suddenly decides to show only the ReCaptcha.

I suspect this is either a bug in Webkit, or in ReCaptcha. But I can't understand what would make Safari treat ReCaptcha this way. Or is it the ReCaptcha javascript that messes with it? It's a complete mystery to me.

I'd love to hear any ideas for workarounds.

**Edit**: One additional detail: once Safari shows only the ReCaptcha, the title of the page is still that of the original page. The source is still the original source. Even the DOM tree looks fine. Yet it only shows the ReCaptcha.

If I replace the recaptcha with another iframe, everything shows up fine. Showing the recaptcha in the page without a modal dialog works fine too. So it's really the combination of Safari + ReCaptcha + jQuery popup that causes the problem.

**Edit**: I just noticed that ReCaptcha only uses an iframe when Javacript is disabled. So my iframe test is irrelevant. It has to be an incompatibility between the ReCaptcha javascript (from Google, so you'd expect decent cross-browser capability), jQuery (generally good at cross-browser stuff), and Safari (Webkit, related to Google's Chrome).

It's still a complete mystery why this specific combination would fail so badly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

`$('#captcha-form script').remove();`

'captcha-form' is the id of the form containing the captcha. Remove the script tags so the scripts don't get executed a second time when Safari re-renders them after jQuery moves them. The event handlers created by the script aren't in the script tags, so they survive.

Works in Safari and Firefox 4. I'm now off to test this in some other browsers.

Comment: Just tested and works: fixes Safari and doesn't break Firefox (4), Chrome, IE (8) nor Opera (11).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and solved it by using the Recaptcha ajax API to create the captcha after the modal div containing it had been opened: http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/display.html

```
$("#EmailSignupModal").dialog('open');

//only call create the first time the dialog is opened.
if ($("#recaptcha_area").length == 0){
   Recaptcha.create("--public key--", "EmailCaptchaContainer", {
      theme: "clean",
      callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
   });
}
```